# Different Link in Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I have a Table in my php File Which has table column(tablecode), and I have links for every value of the (tablecode). for example
for (tablecode) value "1" i want to href it in $link1,
for (tablecode) "2" href it in $link2.
i want it link automatically whenever it determine that the value is "1" or "2" etc.. is this possible? or not?**

```html
$sql1="SELECT tablecode FROM requests";

$lists=mysql_query($sql1);
$link1="http://.....";
$link2="http://.....";
$link="";
```

```html
<?php
while($request = mysql_fetch_assoc($lists)) { 
    echo"<tr>"; 
    echo"<td BGCOLOR=white><a href='$link'>".$request['tablecode']."</a></td>";     
    echo"</tr>";
}

?>
```

should i put

```html
if(tablecode == "1") {
    $link=$link1;
}
```

or what? im too confuse using php and my sql im new here thanks this is for my project

this is the table

[image]

Comment: what is the value for $request['type']?

Comment: ow im sorry .. the value of that is the tablecode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, I'm not sure, but I think you're looking for dynamic variables (see [PHP manual: Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.variables.variable.php) ).

Let's say:

```
$link1="aaa";
$link2="bbb";
```

Then if $tablecode=1, this will give you $link1

```
$link=${"link".$tablecode};
echo $link; // aaa
```

So, in your code:

```
while ($request=mysql_fetch_assoc($lists)){
    $link=${"link".$request['tablecode']};
    echo"<tr>
        <td BGCOLOR=white><a href='$link'>$request[tablecode]</a></td>";
        </tr>";
}
```

Explanation:

```
// writing ${"link1"} means that you are referencing $link1
// so if: $request["tablecode"] is 1 then
$link=${"link".$request["tablecode"]}; 
// is the same thing as $link = $link1;
// but if $request["tablecode"] is 2 then
// you will be referencing ${"link".2} or $link2
```

But, as it was already suggested, arrays are simpler:

```
$links=array("1" => "http://1", "2" => "http://2");
```

then use:

```
while ($request=mysql_fetch_assoc($lists)){
    $link=$links[$request['tablecode']];
    echo"<tr>
        <td BGCOLOR=white><a href='$link'>$request[tablecode]</a></td>";
        </tr>";
}
```

Comment: I know. It was an example. I made a change for your code.

Comment: kindly plss explain it clearly.. its a little confusing

Comment: the value of tablecode is not fix .. so simetimes it will become the 2 first before 1 the value is defending on input from the frontend to database and load to my web which is my backend... is array is the best suggest?

Comment: Both options will work, no matter the order! (the variables are dynamic) But it's better to use arrays because it's easier to keep track of the values, to make changes, it's more scalable etc.

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just put links in array, like:

```
$links = array(1 => 'http://...', 2 => 'http://...')
```

And call them by index:

```
echo "<td BGCOLOR=white><a href='".$links[$request['tablecode']]."'>".$request['tablecode']."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong :

```
while($request=mysql_fetch_assoc($lists)){  
    echo"<tr>"; 
    echo"<td BGCOLOR=white><a href=".$link.$request['tablecode'].">".$request['tablecode']."</a></td>";

    echo"</tr>";
}
```

If `$request['tablecode']` is 1 then href will be `$link.$request['tablecode'] =` `$link1`

Comment: This will not work, because you're just joining two strings ($link and $request[tablecode]), instead of calling a variable dynamically (use ${}). It will just give: "... href="1">1..."